# How can I find out if my app runs native or as webapp?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am writing an app with Sencha Touch and Phonegap. The app should work as native and web app.
But if its native I need to do some different stuff. How can I figure out if my app is
running as web app or native app on a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that,

```
if (Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap) { //do stuff for native }
```